# Sending parallel requests routed to a single endpoint using Apache Camel

Tags: spring, apache-camel, spring-camel

I get suggestions of Multicast,where a single request is routed to multiple endpoints as the snippet below.But the requirement is sending multiple requests in parallel to a single endpoint.

```
<route>
  <from uri="direct:start"/>
  <multicast>
    <to uri="mock:first"/>
    <to uri="mock:second"/>
    <to uri="mock:third"/>
  </multicast>
</route>
```

Comment: that is not possible. How did you test that it is sending multiple requests in parallel to a single endpoint. You can edit your question with those details

Answer (score 0):

You can use **parallelProcessing** option.

```
<route>
  <from uri="direct:start"/>
  <multicast parallelProcessing="true">
    <to uri="mock:first"/>
    <to uri="mock:second"/>
    <to uri="mock:third"/>
  </multicast>
</route>
```